# Ubuntu: make error: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, make

I have the following makefile, I didn't write myself it was part of an installation of TAU profiler. I ran the make command as suggested by the installation steps:

```
make CC=tau_cc.sh
```

Then I got the following errors:

```
make[2]: libpdb.a: Command not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:21: libpdb.a] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/j/Desktop/tau-2.30.1/pdt/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/ductape/lib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:137: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/j/Desktop/tau-2.30.1/pdt/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/ductape'
make: *** [Makefile:13: all] Error 2
```

The makefile looks like:

```
INC = ../inc

.SUFFIXES: .cc .o .pdb .h

CCFLAGS = -I$(INC)

#CXXPARSE = cxxparse
#CXXPFLAGS = -I$(INC)
CXXPARSE = true

PDBOBJS = pdbRead.o pdbMisc.o pdbItem.o pdbGroup.o pdbClass.o pdbModule.o \
      pdbRoutine.o pdbCRoutine.o pdbFRoutine.o pdbTemplate.o \
      pdbGroupField.o pdbWrite.o pdbMacro.o pdbNamespace.o pdbType.o \
      pdbFile.o pdbSimpleItem.o pdbTemplateItem.o pdbFatItem.o \
      pdbTemplateArg.o pdbPragma.o 

all : libpdb.a

libpdb.a: $(PDBOBJS)
    $(PRELINK)
    $(CXXAR) libpdb.a $(PDBOBJS) $(EXTRAOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) 

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<
    $(CXXPARSE) $< $(CXXPFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf core *.o $(PROG) libpdb.a $(EXTRAOBJS) *~
    rm -rf a.out *.ti *.ii ii_files ti_files

# ===========================================================================
# Dependencies generated with:
#   g++ -M -I../inc *.cc | sed -e 's,/opt[^ ]* ,,g' -e 's,/usr[^ ]* ,,g'
#                              -e '/^  \\$/d' -e 's,../inc,$(INC),g'
#
```

This is not the full makefile but where the error rises due to libpdb.a, since I didn't write this I am not sur if the error is as simple as spaces vs tabs. Would someone helps me fix this?

Comment: Possibly `$(CXXAR)` is empty, so `$(CXXAR) libpdb.a $(PDBOBJS) $(EXTRAOBJS)` expands as `libpdb.a $(PDBOBJS) $(EXTRAOBJS)`

Comment: So if it's empty, not sure should I change this line or ?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/docs/newguide/bk01pt01ch01s03.html) mentions loading an environment module (`module load tau`) - did you do so?

Comment: Yes, I got the error: "ERROR: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'tau'" so I was following the installation steps in the main folder instead

Comment: Well you'll need to find some way of assigning values to the variables that aren't assigned inside the Makefile - if you don't have the appropriate modulefile then you can do so on the `make` command line in the same way that you did for `CC` ex. `make CC=tau_cc.sh CXXAR="ar r"` etc. (I don't know what the value should be btw - just guessing)